# How to interpret this format in php

Tags: php

This is the response i am getting through an API.

```
{
    "status": "0",
    "msg": "Incomplete Data"
} 
{
    "status": "0",
    "msg": "The number is invalid."
}
```

What is this format? And How to interpret this in php?

Thanks

Comment: It's called JSON.

Comment: It's invalid JSON. It looks like it was _supposed_ to be JSON, but two JSON objects in a row like that will not be able to be decoded. If that's exactly what you're getting back from a single API call, then the API isn't working correctly. It should look like the JSON in the answer where the objects are enclosed in square brackets and comma separated.